# Angular Object mapping is returning string opposed to number

Tags: angular, string, object, numbers

I am looping through an object to obtain some mappings. They appear fine in the HTML. However, when clicking on a div sending the key to a function, it's being returned as a string, instead of a number. I cannot figure out why.

```
percents = {
    0: 0,
    0.25: 25,
    0.5: 50,
  }
```

```
<div *ngFor="let percent of percents | keyvalue" (click)="updateValue(percent.key)"
```

```
  updateValue(value) {
    this.form.value.answer = value;
    console.log('updateValue value = ', value)
    console.log('updateValue form = ', this.form.value)
  }
```

The first console log returns 0.5 (if i clicked on that)
The second console log returns:

> answer: "0.5"

Is there any reason the value is being transferred as a string, opposed to a number?

Comment: The name of a property on an object is a string. Why not just use an array of objects if you want to treat numbers as numbers?

Comment: Do you have an example? I need the keyvalue pairs for some additional UI bits I'm doing for NgClasses etc

Comment: I would say that mutating your data for the purposes of doing some styling is not the right approach here. If you provide a demo in stackblitz of what you're doing, people can suggest alternative approaches or workarounds.

Comment: Thanks for the response Kurt. I'm not really mutating data. There's a value in the database, such as 0.5, or 0.75. I have a div inside the one mentioned that will simply check ` [ngClass]="(percent.value == '0' && answer== percent.key) ? 'red'. It's to highlight the button of the selected percent. That's all. This question is regarding how to return a number on a click event, opposed to a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared the following object

```js
percents = {
  0: 0,
  0.25: 25,
  0.5: 50,
}
```

This object has the keys `"0", "0.25", "0.5"` and the values `0, 25, 50`. When you send the key back as an event arg, you are sending the key - the string value.

You have this data structure for other purposes and you are keen to keep it this way. This being the case, you need to convert a string into a number. The simplest way to do this is use the Javascript `parseFloat()` function.

```js
const percents = {
  0: 0,
  0.25: 25,
  0.5: 50,
};

for (const key in percents) {
  if (percents.hasOwnProperty(key)) {  
    console.log(key, typeof(key));
    
    const floatKey = parseFloat(key);
    console.log(floatKey, typeof(floatKey));
  }
}
```

In your example you could you it like this:

```js
updateValue(value) {
  this.form.value.answer = parseFloat(value);
}
```

Comment: Amazing. Thank you. My alternative was 5 separate divs hardcoded that call the function with those values. However, wanting to reduce the amount of HTML, i thought it wise to use an object seeing as the database value doesn't match the UI buttons. And I needed a way of highlighting which had previously been selected. Thanks for your time!

Comment: No prob :). There's many different ways to achieve the same goal - this is just one way.